# two way data binding between components without service

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-services

I am newbie in angular 2+, I want to achieve two way data binding between components my need is to pass just one variable's value so creating service won't be good option looking for alternatives for the same.

Comment: You should tag angular 2 instead of angularjs , if a question is related to Angular 2.

Comment: I could not find appropriate tag in angular-2 please suggest edit I'll accept it.

Comment: And yes you can use @input decorator for that.

Comment: I am using decoraters(input,output) and able to get value in child component but that is unidirectional

Comment: can u post your code to jsfiddle

Comment: That issue is resolved I've used combination of input and output and triggering event emitter in both the components will put that in fiddle soon

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass values between two components you can use @Input and @Output event emitters else you can use sessionStorage or localStorage apart from services.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve two-way data binding between components, create @Input and @Output variable for the same property.

```
export class CustomComponent {
  @Input() myvar:any;
  @Output() myVarChange = EventEmitter<any>();
}
```

https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/components/app_structure/two_way_data_binding.html

Answer (score 0):

Follow This approach:

1)Import your component(from where you want value of variable) in second component.
2)Declare it in your constructor and then use its function or variable.

Component1.ts

```
import { component2name } from '../component2.ts';

export class Component1 implements OnInit {

    component1: any;

    constructor( private comp2: component2name ) { }

    this.component1 = this.comp2.function-or-varaible;}
```

I hope this approach will help you out. If you have any question related to this approach please comment i will answered you.